# Not homebrewing, but I need help bottling for medical issues

Tags: bottling, carbonation

I’m not home brewing anything but I recently got some swing top glass bottles with the idea that I could put my store bought sodas in them. I have many medical issues & one of them causes chronic nausea and vomiting so I always have the 2 liters of Sprite, 7up, and Ginger Ale on hand because they are the only ones that help a bit. I can only afford the 2L, the others are too expensive.
I’ve tried to transfer them a couple of times but it’s been a total failure. In reading some comments here, I see that using a funnel is not a good idea? Here’s my problem- a full 2L is pretty heavy at first to pour from and I have a hand tremor so I always have to use a funnel when I pour anything.
Does anyone have any tips on how I can get this done? I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but transferring 2L bottles to smaller Grolsch style flip-top bottles to preserve carbonation just sounds like far more trouble than it could be worth, to satisfy an old wives' tale that white soda and ginger ale help to calm a nauseous stomach.  If you like the white sodas in smaller amounts, and need to minimize costs, look for deals on generic sodas from your local discount store, such as this one which is only 1.9 cents per ounce: https://www.walmart.com/ip/Great-Value-Twist-Up-Lemon-Lime-Soda-12-fl-oz-12-count/10794699

Comment: "*far more trouble than it could be worth*".  For years now, I've been buying 2L bottles of club soda and transferring them to 300mL bottles for individual servings. Small bottles or cans typically cost more than the large bottle. It definitely *is* worth the trouble.

Comment: If you have a lot of experience, then maybe you can help her out by answering the question in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

things 'able' people don't think about, but it makes total sense!

I have sat back in my chair and thought about this for half an hour or so, this is what I came up with, food for thought.

- Buy smaller bottles in bulk (although more initial outlay), makro, bookers... do a deal with the owner of your local corner shop who goes to the 'cash and carry'
- Soda Stream (expensive to run), transfer the large bottles to smaller ones, and fizz them up if/when needed. I have seen 3D printed leavers and other attachments that will make the button easier to push.
- CO2 tank, regulator and fittings (this would be a bit of a project), [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GaC14YpDJHw&ab_channel=BeverageFactory). the tank would last for a very long time (way more than a year if not a couple of years), I use [Adamsgas](https://www.adamsgas.co.uk/) and after your all setup, the running costs would be £15-£20 when you need a refill.

Hope this is of help in some way.